# Programming exercise

Tags: java

Hi I have been doing the Javabat exercises and I have found myself in a bit of a snag with this problem:

We'll say that a String is xy-balanced if for all the 'x' chars in the string, there exists a 'y' char somewhere later in the string. So "xxy" is balanced, but "xyx" is not. One 'y' can balance multiple 'x's. Return true if the given string is xy-balanced.

```
xyBalance("aaxbby") → true

xyBalance("aaxbb") → false

xyBalance("yaaxbb") → false
```

---

```
public boolean xyBalance(String str) {

  if(str.length() < 2){

    if(str == "x"){

    return false;

    }

    return true;

  }

  for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length()- 1;i++){

  if (str.charAt(i)=='x' && str.charAt(i + 1) == 'y'){

  return true;

  }

  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Any exceptions? Unexpected results?

Comment: Consider moving to (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: Let me get this straight! if one `y` can balance multiple `x's` then wouldn't the prescence of a single `y` in the string mean that it is xy balanced, except if the `y` is followed by an `x`?

Comment: Surely this can be solved by starting at the end of the `String` and moving backwards, if you find an `y` first it is balanced, if you find a `x` first it is not.

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the position of the last `x`
2. Find the position of the last `y`
3. Return `xPos < yPos`.

(I'll leave special cases, such as if no `x` or no `y` are found as another exercise ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns true as soon as it finds an `'x'` immediately followed by a `'y'` in the given string. So it will give incorrect results to your original problem in most of the cases.

I don't give you the full solution, only a hint, so that you actually learn to solve the problem yourself. Basically you need to determine whether there is a `'y'` in the string after the last occurrence of `'x'`. For this, use [`String.lastIndexOf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29).

Comment: I underrstand that I dont know how to make the method return true if it finds an y after an x no mater what position it is.

Comment: @user846603, you could have phrased your question clearer, to start with :-) Check my update for a solution hint.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is flawed: you return true (i.e. you end the loop and give a result) as soon as you find an x directly followed by an y. This is not what the program should do.

Also, if the string length is les than 2, you're comparing strings with ==. This compares the references (pointers) and not the contents of the strings. Use s1.equals(s2) to compare the contents of two strings.

Here's how I would code the algorithm (other solutions using indexOf are potentially more efficient, but they don't use a loop. If you want to keep using a loop, this solution should work).

- Initialize a boolean variable `balanced` to true
- start looping on each character of the string.
- if the current character is an x, set balance to false.
- if the current character is an y, reset balanced to true.
- when the loop is finished, return the value of balanced.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean xyBalance(String str) {
    if(!str.contains("x")) { return true; }
    int x = str.lastIndexOf("x");
    int y = str.lastIndexOf("y");
    return x < y;
}
```

From top to bottom:
If there is no x in the string, it must be balanced so return true.
Get the last instance of x.
Get the last instance of y.
If the last x is before the last y, return true, otherwise, return false.

This is the easiest and cleanest way I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to solve this using charAt() and an iteration loop:

```
   public boolean xyBalance(String str) {
      //start from the end of the string
      for (int i = str.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
      {
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'x')
        {
          //starting from the index of the last 'x', check the rest of the string to see if there is a 'y'
          for (int j = i; j < str.length(); j++)
          {
            if (str.charAt(j) == 'y')
            {
              //balanced
              return true;          
            }
          }
          //no 'y' found so not balanced
          return false; 
        }     
      }
      //no 'x' found at all so we are balanced
      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public boolean xyBalance(String str) {
//intialize x and y value to 0
     int x = 0;
     int y = 0;
//run a for loop and check for x value
     for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      if (str.charAt(i) == 'x') {
//if condition is true increment x value
       x++;
//now run a for loop for y only if x condition is true , here it will run from "i" position where we got x value
       for (int j = i; j < str.length(); j++) {
        if (str.charAt(j) == 'y') {
//once we get value which matches 'y' increment y and break from here so that it will not count more 'y'
         y++;
         break;
        }
       }
      }
     }

//after this check x and y count  
     if (x == y) {
      return true;
     } else {
      return false;
     }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
public static boolean xyBalance(String str) {

      boolean xBefore = false;
      boolean yAfter = false;

      for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i)=='x') {
            xBefore = true;
            yAfter = false;
        }
        if (str.charAt(i)=='y') {
            xBefore = false;    
            yAfter = true;
        }

    }
      if (yAfter || xBefore==false) {
          return true;
      }

      return false;
}
```